# Bash: Remove beginning part of string that's random with space as the delimiter

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm using this command:

```
find -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 4
```

And I'm getting output like this:

```
374266 lecture04/address-translation.png
2629 lecture04/lecture04-display.txt
1880 lecture04/lecture04-class16.txt
1828 lecture04/quiz-participation-04.zip
```

How can I use grep, sed, or awk to remove the file size and space from the beginning of the string? While I need to have the file-paths listed in order of size, biggest to small, for my script I don't need to know their exact size after this command. I've been reading the **man pages** and Googling but I'm just not *getting* how to do it. I want it to look like this:

```
lecture04/address-translation.png
lecture04/lecture04-display.txt
lecture04/lecture04-class16.txt
lecture04/quiz-participation-04.zip
```

Once the input is formatted like that I'd like to put each path in it's own cell in an array for the rest of my script.

I feel like this is an *easy* question and when I find similar questions on Stack Exchange they just have a command tailored to the question that I have trouble understanding. If you can answer this would you mind explaining the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This the the job `cut` was invented to do:

```
cut -d' ' -f2-

man cut
```

To populate a shell array named `arr` with the result of a command would be

```
arr=( $(find ... | cut -d' ' -f2-) )
```

If you have file names with spaces:

```
$ cat file
374266 /path to /the file
12345 /path   to another/file

$ cat file | cut -d' ' -f2-
/path to /the file
/path   to another/file

$ IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(cat file | cut -d' ' -f2-) )

$ echo "${arr[0]}"
/path to /the file

$ echo "${arr[1]}"
/path   to another/file
```

Obviously I'm using `cat file` in place of your `find` command, not suggesting you cat files to cut. The above will fail for file names that contain newlines. If you have that, look into `find -print0` and `xargs -0` as the starting point for a solution.

You should use mapfile if available as suggested by @gnourf_gnourf in the comments below:

```
$ cat file
374266 .*
12345 /path   to another/file

$ IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(cat file | cut -d' ' -f2-) )

$ echo "${arr[0]}"
.

$ echo "${arr[1]}"
..

$ mapfile -t arr < <(cat file | cut -d' ' -f2-)

$ echo "${arr[0]}"
.*

$ echo "${arr[1]}"
/path   to another/file
```

`man mapfile` and `man bash` for the syntax of that `mapfile` command line or ask @gnourf_gnourf!

Comment: Will this fail if the file path has a space in it? Also how do I go about piping, if that's the right term, the output into an array?

Comment: When it goes into an array file paths with a space are broken up. It seems a space is the delimiter so `7952096 ./old/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text` goes into the array as: `arr[0] = ./old/Sublime` then `arr[1] = Text`and `arr[2] = 2/sublime_text`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's important when you ask questions to post truly representative data and expected output so we can provide suitable answers as we won't always think of potential issues if you don't provide suitable test cases. In this case if you have file names that contain spaces then you need to set `IFS=$'\n'` to avoid the problem. I updated my answer.

Comment: `IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(cat file | cut -d' ' -f2-) )` is never a good idea! (this is subject to pathname expansion). With Bash≥4: `mapfile -t arr < <(cat file | cut -d' ' -f2-)`. _This the the job `mapfile` was invented to do._ `:)`

Comment: Thank you and I'm sorry. I don't know enough to realize that a space could have been an issue. I just happened to be testing the script in a different dir this afternoon.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf could you show an example of pathname expansion in this context?

Comment: `touch $'I love ponies and stars\nlol *\nand unicorns 䍶'` (ok, it has newlines, I know you'll discard it), `touch '*'` (this one too!), `touch '[edmorton].png' 'e.png' 'd.png' 'm.png'`.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. I updated my answer to show the difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `sed`**

A simple solution using `sed`

Test:

```
    $ cat inputFile
    374266 lecture04/address-translation.png
    2629 lecture04/lecture04-display.txt
    1880 lecture04/lecture04-class16.txt
    1828 lecture04/quiz-participation-04.zip
    $ sed -r 's/^[0-9]+\s//g' inputFile
    lecture04/address-translation.png
    lecture04/lecture04-display.txt
    lecture04/lecture04-class16.txt
    lecture04/quiz-participation-04.zip
```

**What it does**

- `-r` extended regular expression
- `s` substitue command. has format `s/regex/repalcemnt/`
- `/^[0-9]+\s//`

  - `^[0-9]+\s` matches any number of digits followed by space at start of the string `^`
  - `//` here replacement string is `null`, delets the digits

**Using grep**

```
 $ grep -oE '\s.*$' input
 lecture04/address-translation.png
 lecture04/lecture04-display.txt
 lecture04/lecture04-class16.txt
```

**Usage**

Piping any of the commands will give you the output.

eg

```
find -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 4 | sed -r 's/[0-9]+\s//g'
```

Comment: I believe he would want it piped, so it should be: `find -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 4 | sed -r 's/[0-9]+\s//g'`

Comment: If a file path has a space will grep and sed fail?

Comment: I'd never use grep for something like this so idk about that but the sed command would be fine. cut IS the right tool for the job though.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R would you mind explaining the arguments in the sed command? And how would I put this output into a predefined array in my script?

Answer (score 1):

Pipe your command with any of these :
1) With cut

```
cut -d " " -f 2-
```

2) With sed

```
sed -r 's/^[0-9]+ //g'
```

3) With awk

```
awk '{print $2}' /* willnot work if whitespace in filename */

awk 'sub($1,"")' /* will work always */
```

Comment: the awk solution would fail if any file name contains white space.

Comment: `sub($1,"")` is always a bad idea. Imagine if `$1` was `.*`. Also, it will recompile the record and compress all chains of blank chars so it also will fail with file names containing tabs or multiple contiguous spaces.

Comment: @Ed Morton: How that will affect in this case? As per his question, the first column will contain filesize only, always. Please correct if my understanding is wrong. Also provide an example so that i can understand. Thanks!

Comment: Doing `sub(X,Y)` when X is input data is just generally to be avoided. In this case I was thinking you were modifying $1 but you aren't, you're modifying $0 so it won't compress white space as I said it would, it will just leave a leading blank. You should really just use `sub(/[^ ]+ /,"")` though.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `cut`

```
find -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 4 | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

the option '-d' of `cut` means delimeter, here use space as delimeter. But this solution has limitation. If the file-paths contain spaces, it fails.

Also you can use `awk`

```
find -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 4 | awk "{print $2}"
```

`awk` use spaces as the default delimeter. Also fails if file-paths contains spaces

Comment: The awk solution would fail if any file name contains white space, the cut solution would also fail if the file name contains spaces, do not use double quotes around awk scripts (in this case it makes $2 the 2nd arg passed to your shell, not the 2nd field on the line as desired), and both awk and cut solutions have been suggested in multiple earlier answers.

Comment: Sorry! At the time I was editing, I didn't see other answers. Thanks for your advice for double quotes in awk.